# How to iterate json data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am posting json data from jquery ajax to ASP.NET MVC controller methods as follows

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "/ProductTypeAssignment/Save",
                type: "POST",
                data: { delchkboxloglist: JSON.stringify(rows) },
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                success: document.location.reload()
            });


 public ActionResult Save(List<string> delchkboxloglist)
{


}
```

delschboxloglist has the following data in it

> "[{\"Description\":\"Avantis\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"1\",\"SelectProductLine\":true,\"uid\":0},{\"Description\":\"Customer
>   FIRST
>   Support\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"2\",\"SelectProductLine\":true,\"uid\":1},{\"Description\":\"Eurotherm\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"3\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":2},{\"Description\":\"Foxboro
>   IA\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"18\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":3},{\"Description\":\"Foxboro
>   & Eckardt Measurement and
>   Instrument\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"4\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":4},{\"Description\":\"Foxboro
>   SCADA\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"19\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":5},{\"Description\":\"IMServ\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"5\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":6},{\"Description\":\"InFusion\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"6\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":7},{\"Description\":\"SimSci\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"7\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":8},{\"Description\":\"Skelta\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"20\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":9},{\"Description\":\"Triconex\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"8\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":10},{\"Description\":\"Wonderware\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"9\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":11}]"

can you please let me know how do i iterate through this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JQuery iterator as:

```
$.each(delschboxloglist , function (idx, idv) {
 //idx is the index, idv is the object at that index
 var description = idv.Description;
 //do the same for the remaining properties here...
}
```

if you want to process this in C#, one thing you can do is to serialize it to your object. Assume you have a class called Product that contains those properties found in your Json, then you can use JavaScriptSerializer to serialize the json data. See below:

```
 public class ProductTypeAssign
{
    public string ProductLineTypeID { get; set; }
    public bool SelectProductLine { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<ProductTypeAssign> dataList { get; set; }
    public ProductTypeAssign data = null;
    public string UId { get; set; }

}
 public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var test ="[" +
                  "{\"Description\":\"Avantis\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"1\",\"SelectProductLine\":true,\"uid\":0}," +
                  "{\"Description\":\"Customer FIRST Support\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"2\",\"SelectProductLine\":true,\"uid\":1}," +
                  "{\"Description\":\"Eurotherm\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"3\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":2}," +
                  "{\"Description\":\"Foxboro IA\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"18\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":3}," +
                  "{\"Description\":\"Foxboro & Eckardt Measurement and Instrument\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"4\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":4}," +
                  "{\"Description\":\"Foxboro SCADA\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"19\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":5}," +
                  "{\"Description\":\"IMServ\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"5\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":6}," +
                  "{\"Description\":\"InFusion\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"6\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":7}," +
                  "{\"Description\":\"SimSci\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"7\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":8}," +
                  "{\"Description\":\"Skelta\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"20\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":9}," +
                  "{\"Description\":\"Triconex\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"8\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":10}," +
                  "{\"Description\":\"Wonderware\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"9\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":11}" +
                  "]";
        var products = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<ProductTypeAssign>>(test);
}
```

This is returning a list 12 count

Comment: How can i do this in c#? I am passing the grid rows to controller and i want to read it in c#

Comment: Please see the edits I made on the answer above. Also note that, lower case in your json can be deserialized to your Upper case properties of your C# class. :)

Comment: if i do this it is throwing me an error saying 

CS1503 C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string'

 public ActionResult Save(List<string> delchkboxloglist)
{
 var model = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ProductTypeAssign>(delchkboxloglist);
}

Comment: Your parameter need to be string - not List<String>.  Please change the method with:

public ActionResult Save(string delchkboxloglist) { var model = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ProductTypeAssign>(delchkboxloglist); }

Comment: i tried to change it to string but the method is not getting called. when i see in developer tools i get the following error POST http://localhost:11670/ProductTypeAssignment/Save 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: please remove the traditional:true from your ajax call

Comment: thank you. var model = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ProductTypeAssign>(delchkboxloglist); is not deserialising the data. delchkboxloglist has the following data:"{\"ProductTypeAssign\":[{\"Description\":\"Avantis\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"1\",\"SelectProductLine\":true,\"uid\":0},{\"Description\":\"Customer FIRST Support\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"2\",\"SelectProductLine\":true,\"uid\":1},{\"Description\":\"Eurotherm\",\"ProductLineTypeID\":\"3\",\"SelectProductLine\":false,\"uid\":2}}]}"

Comment: producttypeassign class is declared below: public class ProductTypeAssign
    {
        public string ProductLineTypeID { get; set; }
        public bool SelectProductLine { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }


        List<ProductTypeAssign> dataList = new List<ProductTypeAssign>();
        ProductTypeAssign data = null;}

Comment: Looks like UId is missing from the ProductTypeAssign class. You need to add that and try again

Comment: i added uid but model count is 1 and all the values in it has null values.

Comment: Sorry You need to serialize it to List. So please go ahead and change the line with this
 var model = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<ProductTypeAssign>>(delchkboxloglist);

Comment: i tried to change it to list and now the model has count 0. it is not deserialising the data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91649/discussion-between-yohanis-and-xrx215).

Comment: Remove list from parameter and don't stringfy you data. And also change datatype to text instead of json.